# Mongoose update push to start of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to push to the starting of array while updating(a single document). I am using `findOneAndUpdate` but it seems like [mongoose doesn't support $position operator](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2024). I can achieve this by using the native driver by `Model.collection.update`

```
{
    '$push': {
        post_IDs: {
            '$each': [articles],
            '$position': 0
        }
    }
}
```

but the native driver doesn't return the document updated. That's why I can't use it here. Is there any way to push to the start of the array while receiving the updated document in the callback - apart from using `find()` followed by `save()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose does not support the new operators directly, but the underlying driver dependency should be recent enough if your mongoose is a recent release.

You get the underlying "node native" driver functions by using the [`.collection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-collection) accessor on the model:

```js
Model.collection.findAndModify(
    { field: "value" },
    [],
    { 
        "$push": {
            "post_IDs": {
                "$each": [articles],
                "$position": 0
             }
         }
    },
    { new: true},
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```

The method there is the [`.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) from the native driver. The syntax is a little different. First is "query" then a "sort" array, then the "update" document. Also the options are set to return the "new" document, which is what the mongoose methods default to, but this one does not.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!!